# Disable certain features of pdf document

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am using YaHPConverter tool to convert HTML file to pdf file and I want to restrict user for copy, edit, save as, export. Only user should print.

When the pdf is viewed it shows a small strip with the above mentioned options. How can I disable some of the options available on this strip?